# display submit button until errs removed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a rails form using simple_form, client_side_validations and bootstrap.

Is there a simple way to automatically disable the summit button until all the the displayed errors have been removed

Answer (score 2):

you can create a div and put all the error message inside that div. you can check using jquery that if the div length is not zero then disable the submit button else enable it.